# React native ios half screen on navigation

Tags: android, ios, iphone, react-native, mobile-development

on launching the application it goes from splash screen to main screen at their everything is all right but when i try to login or skip my login , gap appears at top of the screen. Any one facing this issue?  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this code in your App.js file:

```
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-navigation";

if (Platform.OS === "android") {
  // removes extra space at top of header on android
  SafeAreaView.setStatusBarHeight(0);
}
```

Comment: android view is alright .. and i have wrapped my code in SafeAreaView. safe area is doin a great job but when i navigate from sign t main screen after login or skipping login screen , then this shows a gap. i have checked my each view at home page , not able to understand what's really happeing